# How to make \textpm (or \pm) monospaced

Tags: fonts, symbols, typewriter

Is it possible to typeset the symbol `\textpm` (or the equivalent math operator `\pm`) using a monospaced font?

I would like to compile something like `\texttt{\textpm}` without errors.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\textpm}
\end{document}
```

The error is `Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: It works for me with no packages. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces that error.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I get “Undefined control sequence”, without packages.

Comment: I removed all the packages and I get "Undefined control sequence". I'm trying to figure out which package makes LaTeX to produce a different error. I edit the question.

Comment: @egreg Oops... The one time I compile using the GUI it goes wrong :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load `textcomp`. Better defining a suitable command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\ttpm}{\textnormal{\texttt{\textpm}}}

\begin{document}

\ttpm

\end{document}
```